# Не увеличивается переменная в замыкании

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Есть функция с классическим счетчиком в замыкании:

```
function sliding(arr) {
            var i = 0;
            return function() {
                arr[i].style.opacity = 0;
                if(i == arr.length - 1) {
                    arr[0].style.opacity = 1;
                } else {
                    arr[i+1].style.opacity = 1;
                }
               i++;
               if(i == arr.length) {
                   i = 0;
               }
               console.log(i);
            }
        }
```

и код использующий эту функцию:

```
function move(item, step) {
            for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                (function(i, step) {
                    var f = sliding(item[i]); //вот здесь использую замыкание 
                    setTimeout(f, step)  // и вызываю новую функцию через таймер, по идее перемменная `i` сохраненная в замыкании должна увеличиваться...А она всегда равна единице
                })(i, step);
                step += 300;
            }
        }
        setInterval(move.bind(this, self.imgs, 2000), 4000);
```

Почему не увеличивается переменная в замыкании?

Comment: item[I] - это массив?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow  да

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, внутри него и делается обход, а счетчик который увеличивается при каждом вызове нужен для доступа к элементам этого массива, только вот увеличивается при первом запуске, и так и остается равным единице....

Comment: @pepel_xD, дайте угадаю: _в консольку всегда выводится 1_?

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар показал, что вызывая `var f = sliding(item[i]);` вы каждый раз создаете **новое замыкание**, с `var i = 0;`. Вот он и выводит каждый раз единичку... Можно считать сеанс дистанционной отладки закрытым?

Comment: все смешалось в кучу. Попробуй описать словами, что ты пытаешься сделать

Comment: @Grundy, есть двумерный массив. при первом запуске функция  делала манипуляции с `arr[0][0] arr[1][0] arr[2][0]....` при втором `arr[0][1] arr[1][1] arr[2][1]....` и так далее циклично. Для чего решил для манипуляций с элементами внутренних массивов использовать счетчик в замыкании, т.е. вызываясь функция отработала с нулевым элементом увеличила счетчик, запустилась еще раз отработала с первым элементом увеличила счетчик и т.д.
Для обхода самого двумерного массива использовал вторую функцию котрая через таймер запускала первую на элементе текущей итерации обхода. Как то так...

Comment: @pepel_xD , а с вложенным `for` не получится?

Comment: @br3t , мне нужно запускать через таймер, т.е. на первом вложенном массиве через 3с, на втором через 3.3с и т.д. Пробовал с двумя циклами, вешало браузер...

Comment: Т.е. у вас есть двумерный массив изображений и вам надо анимировать изображение в каждой строке с временным промежутком между анимациями разных строк?

Comment: @br3t , да именно так

Comment: А вы в сторону css-анимаций не смотрели?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53306/discussion-between-pepel-xd-and-br3t).